# Finding the conditional distribution of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, density-function

**Question**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of accidents which will occur at each of two intersections over the next year. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson random variables , with means $a$ and $b$ respectively. Find the conditional distribution of the number of accidents which will occur at the first intersection over the next year, given the total number of accidents.

**My working**

Let $W = X + Y$

$\implies f_W(w) = \frac {(a + b)^w e^{-(a + b)}} {w!}$

$f_{X \mid W}(x \mid w) = \frac {f_{X, W}(x, w)} {f_W(w)}$

---

This is where I am stuck. I believe that, in order to find the conditional distribution of $X$ on $W$, I need the joint distribution of $X$ and $W$ - I know of no other way to approach the problem. However, I am not sure if I am given enough information to find this joint distribution. In particular, it is obvious that $X$ and $W$ are not independent. How should I continue? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that for $a,b\in \Bbb Z$
$$
\begin{align*}
F_{X,W}(a,b)&=\Pr [X\leqslant a, X+Y\leqslant b]\\
&=\sum_{\{(t,s)\in \mathbb{Z}^2:t\leqslant a,t+s\leqslant b\}}f_{X,Y}(t,s)\\
&=\sum_{(t,s)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty ,a]}(t)\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty ,b]}(t+s)f_{X,Y  }(t,s)\\
&=\sum_{(t,s)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty ,a]}(t)\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty ,b-t]}(s)f_{X,Y}(t,s)\\
&=\sum_{t=-\infty }^a\sum_{s=-\infty }^{b-t}f_{X,Y}(t,s)
\end{align*}
$$
and $f_{X,W}(a,b)=\nabla_a\nabla _bF_{X,W}(a,b)=\nabla_b\nabla_a F_{X,W}(a,b)$ where $\nabla_a g(a,b):=g(a,b)-g(a-1,b)$ for any function $g$, and similarly for $\nabla_b g(a,b)=g(a,b)-g(a,b-1)$, hence you find that

$$
f_{X,W}(a,b)=\nabla_b\sum_{s=-\infty }^{b-a} f_{X,Y}(a,s)=f_{X,Y}(a,b-a)=f_X(a)f_Y(b-a)
$$

if there is no weird mistake somewhere. I'm sure you can finish from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry but I just wanted to check, are the $a$ and $b$ you used in the first equality the same as the $a$ and $b$ used in the question, or are they just arbitrary letters you introduced?

Comment: @EthanMark they are arbitrary letters that I introduced here, I didn't noticed that you used the same letters in your question

Comment: I see. Also, is this like a known proof/identity or something like that?

Comment: Where do the densities and integration come from? These are discrete random variables.

Comment: @Stubborn LOL, I didn't noticed, I assumed they where absolutely continuous random variables. Well I think we can just use PMFs instead of densities and sums instead of integrals. then derivatives must be changed by backward differences also.